# Secure way to store authorization data inside a PWA

Tags: api, rest, authentication, authorization, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to design a secure API, which then will be used by a PWA on desktop and mobile.
I have the following flow:

1. A `POST` request with the user's credentials is issued to endpoint `/session` at login.
2. If the the credentials are correct it will set a `Secure`, `HttpOnly` cookie which contains a refresh token with `Path=/session/renew`. This way it's only sent to that endpoint, cannot be accessed from `JavaScript`, and will only be set on `HTTPS`.
3. The response will also contain a `JSON` object with an access token. This will be used for every other authorized request. It will be passed along in a `Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}` header. The token's max age is 30 minutes.
4. Before the access token expires I can call to `/session/renew` with the cookie set and this will give me new access token and will also set the new refresh token in the cookie with the same properties as above. The old tokens will be revoked on the server.

The access token is stored in a `Redux` store. Unfortunately, this poses a problem.
Now if open a new tab, I can request a new token on `/session/renew`, but with this setup I will "stole" the previous tab's ability to request new tokens as those will be revoked by this call and the user will just get logged-out on that tab.

I see a few solutions, but none seems to be secure enough to me:

- Don't revoke the old access and renew tokens when `/session/renew` is called
- Store the access token in session or local storage

I did quite some research and still don't see what would be the correct (and not too complicated) solution here.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @AndreyStukalin Not really. I just used an off-the-self solution with Keycloak. I use that for the whole authentication/authorization process and it has a built-in support for PWAs.